# stm32f103c8t6 : Problem in PWM generation on timer output channel

Tags: pwm, stm32, arm, embedded

My Objective is to Generate PWM with **duty cycle = 50 %** , **Frequency = 50 Hz** using 
 **General Purpose Timer 2** in output channel 2 which is at PA1 or pin number 11 My Target System is ***STM32 BluePill development board***

- Target Controller is STM32F103C8T6 MEDIUM DENSITY DEVICE
- Target    board crystal is   8 MHz
- I use Keil Micro vision 4 evaluation version IDE for programming and debugging
- Debugger : ST-LINK V2

I configured the GPIOA in Alternate function output Push Pull mode with maximum frequency not exceeding 50 MHz,  I connected an LED bulb to the GPIOA pin 1, but the LED went on glowing without reduction in the brightness level. 
The LED was still glowing even after i performed a test with duty cycle set to 0. On the debugger window I could see exactly all the parameters I configured and the Count register was getting incremented. I cannot find information regarding selection of alternate functions for a GPIO Port.

my code:

```
/**************************** Header file *******************************/
#include<stm32f10x.h>

/*************************** user defined function **********************/

/************************************************************************
Name        : PWM_Init()
Description : Initializes PWM hardware and associated GPIO ports
              Enables clocks for peripherals and configure modes
Parameters  : None
Return_val  : None
************************************************************************/
void PWM_Init()
{

/****configure clocks for PORTA & TIMER2********/

  RCC->APB2ENR |= RCC_APB2ENR_IOPAEN;           // enable port a clock
  RCC->APB1ENR |= RCC_APB1ENR_TIM2EN;           // enable clock for timer 2

/*****  configure GPIOA mode *******************/

   /* Porta Pin 1 &2 as alternate function output Push pull 50 MHz */
    GPIOA->CRL = 0x000000bb;  

/*******Set timer 2 Period for PWM**************        
  Timer Clock                   = 72MHz = 72000000 Hz
  Time Period Required          = (1/50Hz) = 0.02 Seconds
  Let ARR value be 65535 then,
  Prescalar + 1                 = 72000000/((ARR+1)*50Hz)
  Prescalar                     = 21 (approx)   
***********************************************/

    TIM2->ARR = 65535;                      // Set Auto reload value
    TIM2->PSC = 21;                         // Set Prescalar value


    /* Output Compare Mode, ENABLE Preload,PWM  mode:2*/
    TIM2->CCMR1  = 0x00007800; 

    TIM2->EGR |= TIM_EGR_UG;       // ENABLE update generation

    /*CC2E : channel 2 enabled; polarity : active high*/         

    TIM2->CCER = 0x00000010;  

    TIM2->CR1 |= TIM_CR1_ARPE;      // Auto preload ENABLE
    TIM2->CR1 |= TIM_CR1_CEN;       // ENABLE Timer counter     

}
/**************Main Function**********************************/
int main()
 {  
    PWM_Init();                                  // initialize PWM

        while(1)
        {
            TIM2->CCR2  = 32768;                 // SET duty cycle to 50%
        }
  }
```

Kindly have a view of my source code and please notify me the corrections that need to be done. The target specifications are mentioned in the source code.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Finally, after some experiments I found what was going wrong, The problem wasn't really with the code, as ***I configured the PWM mode as Mode 2 the pulse is negative instead of Positive with PWM 1***. So The ***signal is actually inverted***. At duty cycle set to '0', the pulse will be at peak amplitude and LED will glow ( with active high configuration), also because of the fast blinking the decrease in the intensity is not clearly visible even at 50% duty cycle. I changed the **duty cycle to about 80%-90%** and I got the LED getting less illuminated.

Comment: I am trying to create a PWM on a bluepill board and so far have not been able to get anything working. I've tried your code but I am using AC6 for development. There is no <stm32f10x.h> in my environment but instead it has a <stm32f103xb.h>
In any case, I am not getting any PWM out of the board with your program.
Have you tried your program in other environments?

Comment: PS: I created a new clean project and your code works.
Thanks for the simplest working example I have found for generating a PWM on a STM32 MCU. I am working on what I hope to be a portable C++ library but had too many troubles so far with generating PWM. GPIO was working but not PWM. Now I have something to work from. I have to figure out why the same code inside the other project is not working.